# How can I do aggregation with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

when a button is pressed, I can automatically generate a select item and then fill it with the necessary information, and when I select a data, I can print the price information of that data under it. But, for example, when I wanted to sum the prices of 2 select items, I couldn't do it. Please help.

```js
var count = 0;
document.getElementById("createNewSelect").addEventListener("click", function() {
  count++;
  var selectContainer = document.getElementById("newSelectContainer");

  // Yeni select elementi oluştur
  var newSelect = document.createElement("select");
  newSelect.className = "form-control";
  newSelect.name = "fault" + count;
  newSelect.id = "fault" + count;

  var newLabel = document.createElement("label");
  newLabel.className = "control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12";
  newLabel.textContent = "Arıza " + count;

  var firstDiv = document.createElement("div");
  firstDiv.className = "form-group";

  var secondaryDiv = document.createElement("div");
  secondaryDiv.className = "col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12";

  var priceSpan = document.createElement("span");
  priceSpan.id = "pricePlaceHolder";


  fetch('/Home/GetFaultOption')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      const selectElement = document.getElementById(newSelect.name);

      // Gelen verileri döngüyle dolaşıp <option> elementleri oluşturuyoruz
      const placeholderOption = document.createElement('option');
      placeholderOption.value = 0;
      placeholderOption.textContent = "Lütfen Arıza Seçiniz";
      selectElement.appendChild(placeholderOption);

      data.forEach(option => {
        const optionElement = document.createElement('option');

        optionElement.value = option.Id; // Eğer option'da bir değer varsa buraya eklenebilir
        optionElement.textContent = option.Option; // Eğer option'un metni varsa buraya eklenebilir

        selectElement.appendChild(optionElement);
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Bir hata oluştu:', error);
    });



  // Oluşturulan selecti konteynere ekle
  selectContainer.append(firstDiv);
  firstDiv.appendChild(newLabel);
  firstDiv.appendChild(secondaryDiv);
  secondaryDiv.appendChild(newSelect);
  secondaryDiv.appendChild(priceSpan);





  $(function() {
    // Dinamik olarak oluşturulan selectlerin sayısına göre döngü oluşturun
    for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
      // Event listener'ı her bir select elementi için oluşturun
      document.getElementById("fault" + i).addEventListener("change", function() {
        var selectedValue = this.value;
        var priceHolder = this.nextElementSibling;
        $.ajax({
          method: "GET",
          url: "/Home/GetPrice?selectedFaultId=" + selectedValue,

        }).done(function(d) {
          priceHolder.textContent = "(" + d.UnitPrice + " $)";
        }.bind(this)).fail(function(d) {
          if (d.UnitPrice !== undefined) {
            alert("Bir Hata Oluştu.");
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: This is a bad mix of DOM access and jQuery. Please first decide if you want to do Vanilla JS (you are almost there) or jQuery (no need). Also your code can really benefit from delegating instead of adding event listeners in a loop. Can you please try to make a [mcve] especially without the fetch since it does not seem to be relevant to your summing at all. 
WHEN do you want to sum the selects? It does not help that your comments in the code are in Turkish

Comment: Also there is no need to tag c# and asp here. It is a pure JS question, no?

Comment: You're right in your comments. My question was simply about the following: Let's assume each of the composed select items takes 2 options, and these options have specific prices. When I choose one of these options, I can see their prices. However, no matter how many select items are formed, I want to display the total of each individual one on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a plain JS version.
I cannot test it since I do not have your backend. There may be some issues, but the structure is clear

I am not sure why you cannot pass the unitPrice on the first fetch

```js
const selectContainer = document.getElementById("newSelectContainer");
const totalElement = document.getElementById("total");
const countAll = () => {
  const total = [...selectContainer.querySelectorAll("select")]
  .map(sel => +sel.value || 0)
  .reduce((a,b) => a+b) // sum
  || 0;
  totalElement.textContent = `${total.toFixed(2)}$`
};  
selectContainer.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (!tgt.matches("select")) return;

  var selectedValue = tgt.value;
  var priceHolder = tgt.closest(".form-control").querySelector(".pricePlaceHolder");
  fetch('"/Home/GetPrice?selectedFaultId=" + selectedValue')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      if (data.UnitPrice === undefined) {
        alert("Bir Hata Oluştu.");
      } else priceHolder.textContent = `${data.UnitPrice}$`;
    });
  countAll(); // sum  
})


document.getElementById("createNewSelect").addEventListener("click", function() {
  const count = selectContainer.querySelector("div.form-control").length;
  // Yeni select elementi oluştur
  var newSelect = document.createElement("select");
  newSelect.className = "form-control";
  newSelect.name = "fault" + count;
  newSelect.id = "fault" + count;

  var newLabel = document.createElement("label");
  newLabel.className = "control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12";
  newLabel.textContent = "Arıza " + count;

  var firstDiv = document.createElement("div");
  firstDiv.className = "form-group";

  var secondaryDiv = document.createElement("div");
  secondaryDiv.className = "col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12";

  var priceSpan = document.createElement("span");
  priceSpan.classList.add("pricePlaceHolder");


  fetch('/Home/GetFaultOption')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      // Gelen verileri döngüyle dolaşıp <option> elementleri oluşturuyoruz
      const placeholderOption = document.createElement('option');
      placeholderOption.value = ""; // not 0  - must be empty if you want to make it required
      placeholderOption.textContent = "Lütfen Arıza Seçiniz";
      newSelect.appendChild(placeholderOption);

      data.forEach(option => {
        const optionElement = document.createElement('option');

        optionElement.value = option.Id; // Eğer option'da bir değer varsa buraya eklenebilir
        optionElement.textContent = option.Option; // Eğer option'un metni varsa buraya eklenebilir

        newSelect.appendChild(optionElement);
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Bir hata oluştu:', error);
    });



  // Oluşturulan selecti konteynere ekle
  selectContainer.append(firstDiv);
  firstDiv.appendChild(newLabel);
  firstDiv.appendChild(secondaryDiv);
  secondaryDiv.appendChild(newSelect);
  secondaryDiv.appendChild(priceSpan);

});
```